# Installation:Troubleshooting webmin dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I am having a dependency problem dpkg installing [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/download.html) 1.510 (deb) package on Ubuntu 10.04.

I do not know where to look to find info about what dependencies are needed.

Comment: Please do remember that using Webmin on Ubuntu is not recommended or supported (and the webmin package was removed from the official Debian/Ubuntu repositories because of several quality issues with it).

Comment: @Jan: Point taken. In the case of this question it was a matter of not following proper installation procedure.  As the project continues to be updated I hope the past issues of concern will be mitigated.  The latest version is doing wonders on my Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for dependencies is actually listed here: http://www.webmin.com/deb.html

> If Debian complains about missing
>   dependencies, you can install them
>   with the command :
>
> `apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl`
>
> If you are **installing on Ubuntu** and
>   the apt-get command reports that some
>   of the packages cannot be found, edit
>   /etc/apt/sources.list and make sure
>   the lines ending with universe are not
>   commented out.

I followed the instructions and uncommented  "universe" lines in /etc/apt/sources.list which were indeed commented out as the instructions suggested (the file contains more info if you read it). Note: Only two universe lines were commented out in my file but others were not. I made sure all universe lines were uncommented in the entire file and then saved it.

After following the above instructions **dpkg still failed to install webmin, with same message**,  then I used the following *apt-get force* command with no package name. It pushed everything through that didn't go through prior, including the webmin:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Success! :)

---

Note: I found this only minutes after posting the question.
Turns out I was looking for Ubuntu help on the web site menu, but needed to choose Debian help since I'm using the Debian installer.

Comment: I would delete the question. or edit it to be more generic so it is more helpful: Troubleshooting dependencies?

Comment: @gc: Added more info to the title, but the nature of the question *is* very generic.  Others that stumble upon this same issue will find relevant info here considering the questions & answers combined. Deleting a question robs users from benefiting from it in the future!

Comment: I would leave the question, other users may find it useful. Just try to make everything as generic as possible so it benefits most users.